# How similar are the c.e. degrees and the CEA(Cohen) degrees?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, computability-theory

Given reals $A,B,X$, let $A\le_{T/X}B$ iff $A\oplus X\le_TB\oplus X$. For each real $X$ we can define a version of the c.e. degrees over $X$: we look at the preorder on $X$-c.e. reals given by $\le_{T/X}$ (or, if preferred, take the corresponding partial order). Call this $\mathcal{R}_X$; equivalently, $\mathcal{R}_X$ could be given by the reals which are CEA $X$.

My question is the following:

> Suppose $G$ is "sufficiently" Cohen generic. Is $\mathcal{R}_G\cong\mathcal{R}$?

Here $\mathcal{R}$ is the usual c.e. degrees. <s>Incidentally, it's not hard to show that if $G,H$ are "sufficiently" Cohen generic then $\mathcal{R}_G\cong\mathcal{R}_H$.</s> **This is false**.

I vaguely recall a result (due to Shore?) that the answer is **no**, but I can't track it down.

If the answer is no, I'm curious how similar they are nonetheless. For example, do $\mathcal{R}_G$ and $\mathcal{R}$ have the same $\Pi_3$ theories?

Comment: I'm being ignorant here: what does "sufficiently generic" mean?

Comment: It means meeting or avoiding every set of strings from a sufficiently large (countable) collection of sets, e.g. every hyperarithmetic set of strings.

Comment: This old paper of Abraham and Shore is somewhat off-topic but very interesting - https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/plms/s3-53.2.193

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am reading ≅ as meaning "elementarily equivalent."

There are several questions here.  I believe that some of them are accessible by known methods.  The first is that if $X$ is not (low-level)arithmetically definable, then $\mathcal{R}_X$ is not elementarily equivalent to $\mathcal{R}$.  The proof should go by relativising the methods of

Nies, André ;  Shore, Richard A. ;  Slaman, Theodore A.  Interpretability and definability in the recursively enumerable degrees.
Proc. London Math. Soc. (3)  77  (1998),  no. 2, 241--291.

They show that there is a way to interpret the structure of first order arithmetic in the theory of $\mathcal{R}.$  Relativizing, the method should show that there is an interpretation of the structure of first order arithmetic with a predicate for $X$ in $\mathcal{R}_X$.  The elementary difference with $\mathcal{R}$ would be of the form, there is an interpretation of the structure of first order arithmetic with a unary predicate $U$ such that $U$ is not $\Sigma_k$, where $k$ is sufficiently large that it cannot be so represented in $\mathcal{R}$.  It should suffice that $k=10$.

You might look at Shore's paper,

Shore, Richard A.  Degree structures: local and global investigations.
Bull. Symbolic Logic  12  (2006),  no. 3, 369--389,

for a survey of known results and methods.

I agree that it would be interesting to know the exact complexity of the optimal elementary difference.  That question also touches on the old and open problem of deciding the two-quantifier theory of $\mathcal{R}$.  It would be very interesting if working above $X$ a generic, or a random, or anything at, made it possible to decide the two-quantifier theory of $\mathcal{R}_X$.

Comment: This is very nice, thanks! (I had intended "$\cong$" to be isomorphism; as a side question, do you know if it's substantially easier to show that $\mathcal{R}$ and $\mathcal{R}_G$ are not isomorphic if $G$ is sufficiently generic?)

Comment: Re: the last paragraph, I suppose an interesting first step might be: is there an $X$ such that $\mathcal{R}_X$ and $\mathcal{R}$ have different $2$-quantifier theories? That already seems tricky unless I'm missing something.

Comment: It's a little easier to show not isomorphic.  You don't have to show that there is a definable collection of codes for standard models of arithmetic.  You only have to show that there are parameters that code the standard model with a unary predicate for $X$.  By the way, the same observation shows that if $G$ and $H$ are mutually arithmetically generic then $\mathcal{R}_G$ and $\mathcal{R}_H$ are not isomorphic.  They are elementarily equivalent, since every sentence in the theory of $\mathcal{R}_G$ is decided by the empty condition.

Comment: I really like the last point, Ted. Similarly, the theory of $\mathcal{R}_X$ is decided on-a-cone. But since we can't hope to pick out the parameters that code $X$, it must be the case that on-a-cone not every element of $\mathcal{R}_X$ can be definable (in $\mathcal{R}_X$). Which is still open for $\mathcal{R}$, I think.

Comment: @JoeMiller Nice observation. Similarly for sufficiently random and/or generic degrees.

Comment: Very nice: that interesting point never occurred to me.  It's open whether every element of $\mathcal{R}$ is definable.  It would hold if $\mathcal{R}$ could be biinterpretable with first order arithmetic $N$.  Relativizing, $\mathcal{R}_X$ could be biinterpretable with first order arithmetic using parameters to identify an interpretation of $N$ with a predicate for $X$.  Then there would be $\vec{p}$ such that every $d$ in $\mathcal{R}_X$ is definable from $\vec{p}$.  That is also open for $\mathcal{R}$.  Weaker yet, it is open whether the automorphism group of $\mathcal{R}$ is countable.